# xslt template to output special character \ (backward slash)

Tags: json, xml, xslt

```
<xsl:template match="node/@TEXT | text()" name="removequotes">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&quot;'))"><xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($pText, '&#92;&quot;'), '')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="removequotes">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&#92;&quot;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

I have used the above XSLT to print a  `"` and a `\` in the resulting JSON. It outputs me `"HUDSON BAY"` where in I'm excepting the output to be `\"HUDSON BAY\"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find `"` and replace it with `\"`, then the issue is your `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` should be using `&quot;` and not `&#92;&quot;`. Also, you were concatenating an empty string value, instead of what to replace with.

It should be:

```
<xsl:template name="removequotes">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&quot;'))"><xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($pText, '&quot;'), '&#92;&quot;')"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="removequotes">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&quot;')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It might be easier to read (and debug) if you used named parameters for those values:

```
<xsl:template name="removequotes">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  <xsl:param name="find" select="'$quot;'"/>
  <xsl:param name="replace" select="&#92;&quot;"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, $find))"><xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($pText, $find), $replace)"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="removequotes">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, $find)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```